# Is the first scentence grammatically inocrrect?

Tags: grammar

This box is too heavy for me to lift it alone

This box is too heavy for me to lift alone.

Comment: I think both are OK.

Comment: Disagree with this on-hold. As asked, the question clearly indicates that the question is whether the presence of "it" in the first example is incorrect or correct. That would be the 'specific source of concern'.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is clunky, because the pronoun "it" serves no purpose. The infinitive "to lift" doesn't need the object. I don't think I've ever heard a native speaker use the first construction.

Remove the "alone" to see how bad it really is. "This box is too heavy for me to lift it." "This problem is too hard for me to solve it." etc.

Comment: I agree, but realize that I'd acutally use the incorrect version in speech if I were annoyed and asking someone for help. There's actually an identical question on [ELL](https://ell.scktaexchange.com/questions/105280/too-for-object-to-infinitive-object)

Comment: I think the actual answer is that both versions are grammatical, but the first version is stylistically awkward. It's like saying "Bob gave Alice Alice's necklace back after Bob had taken the necklace to the jeweller to repair the necklace on Alice's behalf." You can drop the pronouns, but it sound awful if you do.